# Encode exception from Python script called by Groovy script

Tags: python, unicode, groovy, utf-8

I'm trying to execute Python script from Groovy script :)

Here is how i execute command:

```
def cmd = """guessit -j "$tmp" """
String output = cmd.execute()
```

Where `$tmp` contains file name passed as argument to groovy script.
And i get Unicode error if there is non-ascii characters (i have russian letters in `$tmp`)

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

encoding is UTF-8, `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` is set

Python error log

```
command: guessit -j "Агенты А.Н.К.Л. (The Man from U.N.C.L.E.).2015.WEB-DLRip.mp4" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Soft\Python27\Scripts\guessit-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('guessit==2.0b3', 'console_scripts', 'guessit')()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\guessit\__main__.py", line 150, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\guessit\__main__.py", line 40, in guess_filename
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Python source is here [https://github.com/wackou/guessit/blob/2.x/guessit/**main**.py](https://github.com/wackou/guessit/blob/2.x/guessit/__main__.py)

if i call this command from cmd - there is no errors.
OS is Windows 7. Language for non-Unicode is Russian

Whats wrong?

Comment: That error is coming from Python, probably when you're printing non-ASCII ouput. Please provide the Python source code.

Comment: added python error stack

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!
`SET PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` to set python encoding of stdin, stdout and stderr